# Mouse cursor moving out of window on Minecraft (Chrome OS)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

In Minecraft Java Edition on my Chromebook Duet the mouse cursor just goes out of the Minecraft window when playing instead of centering itself.

I used Pi-Apps in Ubuntu 21.04 (in Crostini) to install Minecraft MultiMC and the install worked and I can play the game but I don't how to fix the problem I described above.

I haven't really tried anything to fix it as there is not really much on the issue.

Lenovo Chromebook Duet: Chrome OS: 94.0.4606.104

Any Help would be appreciated!

Edit:
I'm playing on 1.17.1 with no mods but it seems to do it on every version. It goes out of the window when I move the mouse too far. For example: I need to mine a block to my right, I can get about 1/2 of the way there and then my mouse leaves the window on the right.

Comment: Could you be a little more spicific? When is it going out of the window? What version are you playing on?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this does seem to be a known issue depicted [Here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-19965). I will do a little more research to try to find a solution when I can.

Comment: In the comment, it says: "Java edition as it doesn't suffer this problem". But I am using Java edition so I don't think this is the same issue. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Chrome OS may disallow locking of the cursor. What if you try using a proper Linux desktop. I quickly found this result: https://techwiser.com/how-to-get-linux-desktop-experience-on-chrome-os/. It uses the KDE desktop environment, which unfortunately can be quite glitchy.